# How do I change Bootstrap 3 columns layout on tablet layout?

Tags: html, layout

I'm working on a responsive layout with 3 columns that look like this on desktop:

```
[1] [2] [3] (row => col-md-4)
```

When I resise it for tablets, the layout should change into this form:

```
[2] (full width => col-md-12)
[1] [3] (underneath => col-md-6)
```

How can I arrange this only for tablets and keep the 3 columns layout for desktop only?
Ty

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by duplicating the [2] element and hide the original one with media query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a media query .
Set the max-width to about 500px and see how that works.
Media queries are used in css and start workning with a specific width.
Of course there are many uses but with some googling of media queries you will easily get your answer.

Argus.